# HTML canvas switch and error message

Tags: javascript, regex, html, canvas, onchange

I have run into a little problem in my code.

Take a look at it here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ez56zat5/6/)

What I want to do is to get an error message if you type in a wrong value at size and color.

I tried to make this work, but I can't seem to manage.

```
document.getElementById('MyForm').onchange = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch (myColor) { 
        case '/':
            if (input.value ? '#' + input.value : '#333') {
                result = input.value;
            } 
            else {
                result = 'Six numbers or letters!';
            }
            break;

    }
    document.getElementsByName('result')[0].innerHTML = result;
};
```

The code is for the color, for example, you can't type `#0000000`
I want to do the same for the size. I just want the user to be able to choose a size from `1px` to `300px`.

EDIT

In my HTML  `#<input id="myColor" type="text" pattern="/([A-F0-9]{6}|[A-F0-9]{3})/i" placeholder="Exempel: 0088FF" />`

JS:

```
document.getElementById('MyForm').onchange = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
$('div').click(function(){

if($('input').val().length > 6){

return "Error"

$('div').css('background-color', "#" + $('input').val());
}
    document.getElementsByName('result')[0].innerHTML = result;
};
```

Does not work :(

Comment: One suggestion. You can give input field of number type with min and max values set for "size"

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Can you please explain a bit more? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need validation off course in your canvas click event like. I used JS pattern matching

[**Updated Fiddle Link Fro Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ez56zat5/14/)

```
context.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) 
{                                
    var isValidInput = doValidation();
    if (!isValidInput)
        return;

    if(!drawnOnCanvas){
        clearCanvas();
        drawnOnCanvas = true;
    }        
    var mouseX = event.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop;        
    context.beginPath();        
    context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, size.value / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);        
    context.fillStyle = input.value ? '#' + input.value : '#333';             
    context.fill();
});
```

---

```
function doValidation()
{
    var isValidInput = validateColor();    
    if(!isValidInput)
    {
        console.log("Invalid Color");
        document.getElementById('myColor').focus();
        return false;
    }

    isValidInput = validateSize();    
    if(!isValidInput)
    {
        console.log("Invalid size");
        document.getElementById('mySize').focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function validateColor()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('myColor').value;
    var reg = /^([a-f|A-F]|\d){3,6}$/; // a to f (lower or upper case)
    // or digit of length 3 to 6 this length is valid for color
    var res = reg.test(val);
    return res; //true or false
}
function validateSize()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('mySize').value;
    var reg = /^\d{1,6}$/;
    var res = reg.test(val);
    return res; //true or false
}
```

Comment: thank you! But the alert box for myColor..the alert box comes up several times instead of just once. do you have any idea on how to make the alert box only appear once. Right now you have to click "OK" soooo many times.

Comment: Yes. I would.. I will do soon, but initially would tell u that, Thing is you will get alert only when you click canvas with a wrong input. Just make your input correct and then click canvas..

Comment: my problem is that the alert box doesn't disappear when you click "OK". When you click OK another alert box with the same message shows.

Comment: please help me if you can @Sami

Comment: That is why we use fiddle demo.. I am unable to see the problem you are facing. When I get an alert on demo link. It does not appear again on clicking ok. However i could only suggest to use a div to get validation feedback instead of alert. I have added a div having id='color_feedback'. See the updated fiddle link. Problem is somewhere else, but it would solve multiple alert problem

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you're using a `switch` statement with an IF inside it... that by itself is not good practice.

the `switch` **is** an IF

```
switch (myColor) {
    case '/':
```

This is basically saying:  `if(myColor == '/'){`

Which I'm guessing it never will?

A switch should look like this:

```
switch (myColor) {
    case '#333':
        result = input.value;
        break;
    default:
        result = 'Six numbers or letters!';
        break;
}
```

where the `default:` is the `else`

Secondly, you should be using either RegEx or something much more simple than a switch for this.

**EDIT**

Because you are checking for a color it's not as simple as checking how long the string is. you are only allowed the letters `A-F` and numbers `0-9`. Which means `#GHJKQW` would pass, but not be a valid color.

To get around this you're going to want some RegEx.

if you don't know how to use it I suggest reading up on it, I could not explain it as well as others.

this, however, is the search string you want.

`/([A-F0-9]{6}|[A-F0-9]{3})/i`

This says: "either 3 or 6 characters in length of any letter from a-f, and any number from 0-9"

Comment: Can you describe the last part a bit more, please.

Comment: I still have the same problem... I'm not familiar with your way of doing this but I really want to understand. I don't understand where exactly to use your suggestion in my code.

Comment: Sorry, this is the way to be doing it. I was trying to explain the way you are doing it but you don't want to be learning bad practices.